# Spring can't load static resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to load static resources such as css files and javascript files in my jsp files using relative paths, but it seems by servlet mappings are overriding the mapping to them.

Project structure:

```
webapp/
   assets/
      scripts/
         dashboard.js
      styles/
         common.css
   WEB-INF/
      views/
         pages/
            home/
               body.jsp
```

web.xml:

```
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

...
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
    <import resource="applicationContext.xml" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nickythorne.controller" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" >
    <property name="definitions" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-definitions.xml" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
```

I my JSP file where i'm trying to load the stylesheet:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<base href="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/assets/styles/common.css'/>" />
```

The error I get is:

> WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound:1108 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/project/assets/styles/common.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is:

```
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${root}/assets/styles/common.css"/>
```

`${root}` will be resolved into your relative context path regardless of ports, protocol, domain name etc.

Comment: c:url automatically prepends the context to the path.

Comment: the issue is with the dispatcher trying to resolve the path /project/assets/styles/ as a view. But obviously it can't be found as it doesn't exist. I need to somehow exclude the /assets/** path from the servlet.